# How can I use values from a form's input fields in an INSERT query?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a form for adding a customer into a table, and I'm trying to write the query for it. I'm having trouble getting the values from the form's input fields (name, address etc.) and putting it into the query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the controls on the form or the fields in the recordset. They may or may not have the same values depending on whether the form is dirty or not.

A simple query might be 9query design window)

```
UPDATE ATable SET AName=Forms!Form1!txtName

INSERT INTO ATable ( AName ) Values ( Forms!Form1!txtName )
```

In the code belonging to the form you could say

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDB

sSQL = "UPDATE ATable SET AName='" & Replace(Forms!Form1!txtName,"'","''") & "'"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

sSQL = "INSERT INTO ATable ( AName ) Values ('" _
     & Replace(Forms!Form1!txtName,"'","''") & "')"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```